# How to attach php documentation in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

Is there any way to attach PHP docs in eclipse, so that if I hover over any function I could get all the details and the related description.

Something on similar lines to javadocs.

Using:

1. Eclipse: helios
2. php5.
3. OS: Ubuntu 12.04

[image: PHP manual add window]

Comment: Specify name for php_doc

Comment: Silly mistake. you are right Mahesh Meniya :) Just the name was missing. The directory containing the local docs is just required. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @all who have come here for an answer, just specify the local directory of the docs you extracted, and give it a **site name**. The answer that is awarded the bounty is specific to windows os, and that answer lead to find the mistake in my case, hence I have awarded the bounty to him. Thanks

Comment: @mahesh grave mistake, awarded the bouty to different answer by mistake. The order of answers keep changing :( Can't figure out a way to undo. Sorry. Have asked a question on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140290/bounty-awarded-to-a-different-answer-by-mistake) to re assign a bounty.

Comment: Thanks Try this link :http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50745/op-accepted-wrong-answer-by-mistake-in-featured-question?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is step for configure PhpDoc into eclipse :

**1.** Open eclipse IDE 
**2.** Then select **Window Menu** & Select **Preferences**

[image]

**3.** Then navigate through php menual

[image]

**4.** After Cliking on **New** You will get this Window :
Here specify latest **.chm File** Give Name and Press Ok.

[image]

**5.** Set it to default & press Ok [ It will display in bold letter]

[image]

**6.** After Setting it to default you will get your local help will highlighted with bold letter

[image]

**7.** When you want to see doc for php function then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

[image]
**Note :** You can also change help option from Window -> Preferences

Comment: I need to see the docs for the php functions and classes, not for the user defined classes. Please let me know if you have any question? Thanks for the above explanation, but it's doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: @mtk : Ok, Try this to attach PhpDoc

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have the .chm file, but on clicking new, i get option to add a local directory and the drop down for the file extension has only options for 'html','htm' and 'php'. Added the screenshot. please check. Still unable to attach the doc for local viewing of the php docs.

Comment: @mtk see the detailed steps for adding PhpDoc.

Comment: oh. Thanks for all the effort you took, but I am on linux and I can see only 2 options in the Add Php Manual Window as given in my screenshot. .chm is purely for windows I guess. So, any linux solution please for attaching the php docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Create a new PHP Project (File->New->PHP Project)
2. Switch to the PHP perspective (Window->Open Perspective->PHP)
3. Create a PHP file

If you now write something like

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and hold your mouse over "phpinfo" you should get a popup with the information.
Hold CTRL to jump directly into it.

If you want to documentate your own code use the following:

```
/**
 * Some text here
 * @param string $str input
 * @param array $arr data
 * @return boolean
 */
```

hope that will help you.

Cheers

Comment: I can't see documentation on mouse hover. I do get to see the code on clicking while pressing the CTRL key. Please let me know, how to attach the php doc? Thanks