# eclipse php not work Open PHP Manual option

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I downloaded PDT: Eclipse PHP Development Tools for Windows x64. When I hover the mouse over php keywords and internal (built-in) functions don't show me the tooltip with the description of that word.

Also when right click on the word and select Open PHP Manual, from the context menu, doesn't open the manual.

Anyone knows how correct this issue?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612727/php-manual-for-eclipse

Comment: this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457873/how-to-attach-php-documentaion-in-eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attach php documentaion in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457873/how-to-attach-php-documentaion-in-eclipse)

Comment: I followed that suggestion, but not worked.